# How to check for rows with a certain condition or just check if the reference is empty or does not exist?

Tags: sql, postgresql

[Fiddle 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6eb18/4)

Expected Result:

```
+------------+
| laborer_id |
+------------+
|          5 |
|          6 |
+------------+
```

[Fiddle 2 (with `project_customized_line_schedule` having no rows)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/aa535)

Expected Result

```
+------------+
| laborer_id |
+------------+
|          4 |
|          5 |
|          6 |
+------------+
```

What I wanted is to get the `laborer_id`'s (of first table) where:

- the value of `step_id` = 10 and has a NULL `date_finished` (`step_id` and `date_finished` are in the second table linked by `line_id`)
- OR if that condition is not met, I'd get the `laborer_id`'s of the first table where doesn't exist a `line_id` of the first table in the second table.

The fiddle above works as expected (`laborer_id`'s of 5 and 6 as output) ONLY IF there are rows for some reason. Try deleting the INSERT statement to the `project_customized_line_assignment` table to see. There are no rows at all (as seen on the second schema). If I'm not mistaken (hopefully not a brain fart), all 3 `laborer_id`'s should appear. How can I resolve this? I hope that I constructed the question just fine.

Comment: You probably want `LEFT JOIN` But you need to provide your desire result so we can understand what you need. check [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6eb18/6).

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I need 5 and 6 `laborer_id`'s. If there are no rows on `project_customized_line_schedule` it should output all 3 `laborer_id`'s.

Edit: I added a [second fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/aa535) where all 3 should appear.

Comment: I need you include the desire result (preferible in table  format) so I know what you need and build the query

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Is it okay now?

Comment: Yes, that help let me look at it again

Comment: What about `select laborer_id 
from project_customized_line_assignment a, project_customized_line_schedule s 
where a.line_id = s.line_id and s.step_id = 10 and date_finished is null 

union 

select laborer_id 
from project_customized_line_assignment a2 
where not exists(select * from project_customized_line_schedule s2 where s2.line_id=a2.line_id);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need use **[LEFT JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)** this will try to match every row in the left table with one or more rows on the right, if doesn't find a match then still keep the left row but with NULL for the right fields.

Then you have a case statement to validate both conditions.

```
SELECT *
FROM project_customized_line_assignment AS asm
LEFT JOIN project_customized_line_schedule as scd
  ON asm.line_id = scd.line_id
WHERE CASE WHEN scd.line_id IS NULL THEN true -- if JOIN doesnt find a match line_id is NULL
           WHEN scd.step_id = 10 and scd.date_finished IS NULL THEN true           
      END 
;
```

**[First case](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6eb18/16)**: 2 rows

**[Second case](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/aa535/11)**: 3 rows

Comment: Thank you! So if all case conditions are not met when ELSE is omitted what falsy value does it return? I just have never used CASE while omitting ELSE.

Comment: Yes. if you omite `ELSE` the default is `ELSE null`